# Is it possible to create a table like this (image attached below) in tkinter treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

[image]

All of the example I've saw in the internet only has a single column and row. For example I have this list:

```
list =  [[Name, Contact, Address, [["Fee", 3], ["Foo", 3]]],
         [Name, Contact, Address, [["Fee", 3], ["Foo", 3], ["Faa", 7]]],
         [Name, Contact, Address, [["Fee", 3]],["Fee", 3], ["Faa", 7], ["Poo", 1]]]]
```

How can I make a table out of this list?

*Note: I will have a function that sort the table based on name or address

Comment: No, not in Treeview. You could use a standard grid of labels using the rowspan option.

Comment: ohh, okay. Thank you for suggesting

Comment: i forgot but is it also good to use, the standard grid of labels, when I will have a function that sorts the table based on name?

Comment: If it gets the job done, it is good.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that in treeview. You can't have cells that span rows.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll stick with labels and grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a different treeview for the left elongated and right compressed separately. Then add linespacing to the left treeview to make it look elongated. Make sure to have rowspan of both the treeview same to have the same height in both of them.

Comment: _Easier said than done_, why don't you provide an example to support your statement.

Comment: i accept it is a bit of work, but the question was only whether u can do it not whether it is easy or difficult